# Short titles, Journal abbreviations, etc. in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, acronyms

I've been making the switch toward using `biblatex-chicago` to replace an old `.bst` (now out-dated), but I'm still confused as to how `biblatex` handles short-forms and abbreviations. For example, when I cite an article from the journal *Vetus Testamentum*, I want the footnote to use the abbreviation *VT*, but the bibliography to use the full form. In my old `.bst` file I used the .bib field `shortjournal`, but that doesn't seem to be the way `biblatex` works. Similarly, I would like to be able to abbreviate commonly cited reference works, e.g. *Ancient Near Eastern Texts* as *ANET* in my footnotes, and use it's full form in the bibliography.

I'm guessing that this functionality is built into `biblatex`, I just don't know how to use it.

Comment: I've never done it myself, but probably have a look at the section 4.3, page 151 of the biblatex documentation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a few different fields you can use:

- `shorthand`: Replaces the entire citation label. In verbose/"notes" styles, this abbreviation is used after the first citation.
- `shorttitle`: Replaces `title` if it appears in the citation label.  In verbose/"notes" styles, this abbreviation is used after the first citation.
- `shortjournal`: Defined in the default data model, but not used in the standard styles or `biblatex-chicago`.

To incorporate `shortjournal` in the standard styles, you can modify the `journal` bibliography macro from `biblatex.def` in your preamble:

```
\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcitation} and not test {\iffieldundef{shortjournal}} }
    {\printfield[journaltitle]{shortjournal}}
    {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}
       {}
       {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
          \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
          \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
          \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}}}
```

The `biblatex-chicago` styles have been tailored to meet the requirements of CMS. They are much more complicated than the standard styles and therefore difficult to modify. The following edit for the `journal+sub` macro from any one of the package's `cbx` files should work for most cases:

```
\renewbibmacro*{journal+sub}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcitation} and not test {\iffieldundef{shortjournal}} }
    {\printfield[journaltitle]{shortjournal}}
    {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}
       {}
       {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
        \printfield[noformat]{journaltitle}%
        \setunit{\addcolon\addspace}%
        \printfield[noformat]{journalsubtitle}}}}}
```

Comment: Audrey, since, by now, at least some of these features were fully implemented in biblatex-chicago, and are easily accessible: do you mind updating your answer to reflect these changes? That would be great!

Answer (score 7):

If you have `shortjournal` fields and use the `biber` backend, you can do

```
\DeclareSourcemap{%
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    % Journal abbreviations
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=shortjournal]
      \step[fieldset=journaltitle,origfieldval]
    }
  }
}
```

Many sites I download citations from (into `Zotero`) provide `Journal Abbr` (= `shortjournal` in the `Better BibLaTeX` export) but some do not. Then I need to add, for example

```
\DeclareSourcemap{%
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    % Journal abbreviations
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=journaltitle, match={Physics Letters A},
      replace={Phys. Lett. A}]%
    }
  }
}
```

Or put that in the Zotero database.

Comment: Isn't `\regexp{.+}` going to match everything? In that case, I would suggest simply using `\step[fieldsource=shortjournal, final]`. This will only terminate if `shortjournal` is empty (the same as your code, but without firing up regex). I haven't checked, but maybe the `final` isn't even needed, so `\step[fieldsource=shortjournal]` might suffice.

Comment: Well `\regexp{.*}` would match everything, even an empty field, I thought I needed to be safe against that. But I just tried an empty `shortjournal` field; it turns out biber deletes that, so that the original `journaltitle` would be used. So you are right, there is no need to check the field is nonempty. I changed the above code.