# Map shortjournal into journaltitle

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, biber

I have the following bibliography

```
@article{SomeCiteKey,
  title = {SomeTitle},
  author = {SomeLastname, SomeName},
  date = {SomeDate},
  shortjournal = {SomeAbbr},
  volume = {SomeVol},
  pages = {SomePages},
  doi = {SomeDoi},
  number = {SomeNum}
}
```

As you can see there si no journal or journaltitle entries.

I would like to map the shortjournal entry into journaltitle, such that biber would read the shortjournal field as it is journaltitle. Is this possible? I guess it can be done with `\DeclareSourcemap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For almost all other fields this would be incredibly straightforward.

Use

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=<bib field>, fieldtarget=<internal field>]
    }
  }
}
```

to map `<bib field>` to `<internal field>`. If you pass the `overwrite` option to `\map`, Biber will overwrite `<internal field>` if it exists. If the option is not set, Biber will not do anything if `<internal field>` is present.

In case you want to use `overwrite`, this works directly for `shortjournal` (`<bib field>`) and `journaltitle` (`<internal field>`):

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=shortjournal, fieldtarget=journaltitle]
    }
  }
}
```

An alternative, but slightly more verbose version, can be found in [Jan-Åke Larsson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/47419/jan-%c3%85ke-larsson)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171588/35864) to [Short titles, Journal abbreviations, etc. in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66549/35864).

If you don't want to override an existing long journal name, however, you need to keep in mind that `journal` is remapped to `journaltitle` by a driver-level sourcemap (which is executed after user-level maps). In that case the easiest way out seems to be to perform the mapping from `journal` to `journaltitle` ourselves

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=journal, fieldtarget=journaltitle]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=shortjournal, fieldtarget=journaltitle]
    }
  }
}
```

I guess you want the `overwrite` solution, so here is an MWE demonstrating that

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=shortjournal, fieldtarget=journaltitle]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{uthor:jt,
  title        = {Some Title},
  author       = {Anne Uthor},
  date         = {1982},
  shortjournal = {Lng Nm.},
  journaltitle = {A Long Journal Name},
  volume       = {12},
  pages        = {45-48},
}
@article{uthor:j,
  title        = {Some Title},
  author       = {Anne Uthor},
  date         = {1984},
  shortjournal = {Anoth. Lng. Nam.},
  journal      = {Another Loooong Journal Name},
  volume       = {9},
  pages        = {103-156},
}
@article{uthor:n,
  title        = {Some Title},
  author       = {Anne Uthor},
  date         = {1983},
  shortjournal = {Shrt. Jour.},
  volume       = {12},
  pages        = {45-48},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{uthor:jt,uthor:j,uthor:n,sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Uthor, Anne (1982). ‘Some Title’. In: Lng Nm. 12, pp. 45–48.//— (1983). ‘Some Title’. In: Shrt. Jour. 12, pp. 45–48.//— (1984). ‘Some Title’. In: Anoth. Lng. Nam. 9, pp. 103–156.]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted but didn't know how to use \DeclareSourcemap, thank you for this and the alternative solution.

Comment: @Saavestro There are some usage examples for `\DeclareSourcemap` in the manual (pp. 197-203 in v3.14, §4.5.3 *Dynamic Modification of Data*). They don't cover everything, but together with the explanation of the `\DeclareSourcemap` options on the previous pages you should probably be able to piece together most basic uses.