# Change references from verbose-inote style to endnotes following the same design

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, endnotes, footmisc

I am working on a proposal with a page limit, and I am running out of space. I am using verbose-inote for the references because is the style to use for the proposal. However, I am having problems of space and I would like to move all the references as endnotes at the end of the document with the same format that I have for the verbose-inote to gain some space.

I have this (messy) code as MWP:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}



\usepackage[stable,para,hang]{footmisc}

\makeatletter
\footglue=.1em plus.15em minus.15em

\long\def\@makefntext#1{\leavevmode
  \@makefnmark\nobreak
  #1%
}

\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,maxcitenames=1,backend=bibtex,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,giveninits=true,abbreviate=true,ibidpage=true]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[r]{\smartcite}{\smartcites}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}\addnbspace #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}\addnbspace #1}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%<---- was \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
  
%This delete the title of the journal when is repeated

\newbibmacro*{footcite:note}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{label}}
    {\printnames{labelname}}%
  \ifsingletitle
    {}
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
    \iftoggle{cbx:pageref}
      {\ifsamepage{\the\value{instcount}}
                  {\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}
         {}
         {\addcomma\space\bibstring{page}\addnbspace
          \pageref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
      {}}}


\newcommand{\TODO}[1]{{\textcolor{red}{[\textbf{TODO:} #1]}}}
% \titlespacing\section{0pt}{6pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
% \titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{6pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
% \titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{6pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\let\oldfootnotesize\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{8bp}{1em}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cite}{\autocite} % citations in footnotes
\bibliography{Mendeley,Zotero}

\headheight=14pt


\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@ixpt{8}%
   \abovedisplayskip 8\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\makeatother




%\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}

test\cite{Zhu2020} and \cite{Wolf2020} repeat \cite{Zhu2020}

\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image: And this is the result:]

[image]

What I would like is to have all the references of the document as endnotes but following the same design. In this case, I will avoid repetitions and hopefully win some space. Something like that:

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easily possible to redirect `biblatex`'s footnote citations to endnotes with the option `notetype=endonly`.

The following MWE uses `enotez` to typeset paragraph-style/inline endnotes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{enumstar}{list}{list-type = {enumerate*}}
\setenotez{list-style=enumstar}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, 
  style=verbose-inote,
  maxcitenames=1, giveninits=true, 
  doi=false, isbn=false, url=false, abbreviate=true,
  ibidpage=true,
  notetype=endonly]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[r]{\smartcite}{\smartcites}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}\addnbspace #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}\addnbspace #1}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%<---- was \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{footcite:note}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{label}}
    {\printnames{labelname}}%
  \ifsingletitle
    {}
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
    \iftoggle{cbx:pageref}
      {\ifsamepage{\the\value{instcount}}
                  {\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}
         {}
         {\addcomma\space\bibstring{page}\addnbspace
          \pageref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
      {}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
test\autocite{sigfridsson} and \autocite{worman} repeat \autocite{geer}

\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image: 1. E. Sigfridsson et al. Journal of Computational Chemistry vol. 19, no. 4 (1998), pp. 377–395. 2. N. Worman. Style in Greek Literature. Austin: University of Texas Press, 2002. 3. I. de Geer. “The Orkney Earldom of the Twelfth Century. A Musicological Study”. PhD thesis. Uppsala: Uppsala Universitet, 1985.]

---

I have doubts that this helps you save significant space. After all you get the same behaviour for repeated citations in footnotes and endnotes: A subsequent citation will still issue a new footnote/endnote with its own contents.

You may get better results if you base your style on `style=numeric,` and create an inline bibliography ([Inline bibliography avoiding the list format?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/250204/35864)).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, 
  style=numeric, sorting=none,
  maxnames=1, giveninits=true, 
  doi=false, isbn=false, url=false, abbreviate=true,
  autocite=superscript]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}\addnbspace #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}\addnbspace #1}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{title}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%<---- was \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\noindent}
  {\unspace\endgraf}
  {}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}}

\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod\space}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\footnotesize}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
test\autocite{sigfridsson} and \autocite{worman} repeat \autocite{geer}

test\autocite{sigfridsson} and \autocite{worman} repeat \autocite{geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [1] E. Sigfridsson and U. Ryde. “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. Journal of Computational Chemistry vol. 19, no. 4 (1998), pp. 377–395. [2] N. Worman. The Cast of Character. Style in Greek Literature. Austin: University of Texas Press, 2002. [3] I. de Geer. “Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald – and Music. The Orkney Earldom of the Twelfth Century. A Musicological Study”. PhD thesis. Uppsala: Uppsala Universitet, 1985.]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the second option!! I have further questions based on this answer. I fixed that not appear the title of the articles. Before, I had some specifications using footmisc to save space, can I reduce maximum space between lines of the references and hopefully between words?. Also, the citation in the text when is around a comma o period, appears after the punctuation, is possible to put just after the text. The variable maxcitenames=1 seems not to work for articles with 2 and 3 authors. Finally, is it possible to put in red colour the references in the text and in the bibliography?

Comment: @AlbertAcedo You can change the font setup of the bibliography with `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\tiny}` (in your MWE you several convoluted redefinitions of `\footnotesize` that I did not understand, so I removed them, but you could probably use something similar here as well.) In a current version of `biblatex` you can add `\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{superscript}{\supercite}{\supercites}` to the preamble to stop the punctuation from moving. `maxcitenames` applies only to citations, for the reference section you want `maxbibnames`. You can combine them by setting `maxnames=1,`.

Comment: @AlbertAcedo I slightly edited the answer, now `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{8pt}{8pt}\selectfont}` should work for really tight typesetting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I have followed the instructions and it works! Final doubts ;) I use this expression \renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{7pt}{7pt}\selectfont}, now they have a lot of space between lines, can I reduce this space as much as possible to save space? I changed the color of references in the text to red using hyperref, but I want also put the same color in the reference section number, can you help me with that please? Finally, is there some way to abbreviate the journal name automatically? THANKS A LOT!

Comment: @AlbertAcedo Are you using the fixed definition of `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}` with `\endgraf`? For the colour it may help to say `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}`. No, there is no automatic way to comprehensively abbreviate journal names in `biblatex`. You can use JabRef and its journal name database, or you need to manually define everything (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66549/35864)

Comment: Hi! the color code work! Regarding the bibliography I have defined like this \defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\noindent}
  {\unspace}
  {}
I was playing with \endgraf but still I can not get to reduce the space between lines. What I need is to have the bibliography as condense as possible... Thanks!

Comment: @AlbertAcedo You need the `\endgraf`. The definition should read `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\noindent}
  {\unspace\endgraf}
  {}` with that `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{7pt}{7pt}\selectfont}` works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally works! Appreciate your effort ;)

Comment: @AlbertAcedo If the answer helped resolve your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the green checkmark on the top right to show that the problem is resolved. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.